# Navigate back to xamarin forms page from a xamarin.ios' viewcontroller

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I just wanted to know how can we navigate back from a xamarin.ios viewcontroller to a xamarin.forms page. the page is in PCL and from it i am naviagting to my viewcontroller using dependency service. now i want to go back to my forms page when a back button is hit in my viewcontroller

Comment: What is the relationship between two forms page? Page A navigate  to page B?I suggest that you can provide a sample so that I can test it on my side.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController you can just call Dismiss (on the touched up event of your button)  and it will return to the previous page.

```
this.DismissViewController(false, null);
```

[Here](http://krystianczaplicki.com/mobile/xamarin-ios-view-controller-in-xamarin-forms-app/) is a small simple tutorial with DependencyService and navigating to Native Pages

Comment: cacerio thanks but i want to know that can we navigate to a forms page from a native viewcontroller like for eg i have two forms page and from the second one i navigate to a native viewcontroller now if i dismiss my viewcontroller it will take me back to second page right? what i want to know that is it possible to navigate to first page from the view controller?